# Що таке "рінерит"? Домонтович вигадав слово?

Tags: значення-слів

У романі "Доктор Серафікус" Віктора Домонтовича:

> — Що це? — питає Ірця, показуючи малюнок доби палеоліту, де на камінці вирізьблено не то ведмедя з головою коняки, не то коняку з лапами ведмедя.
>
> — Це, — пояснює Комаха з щирою й непідробленою сумлінністю людини, що звикла ніколи не зважати на авдиторію, — це **рінерит** з оріньякської стоянки Реб'єр.

Цього слова немає в жодному словнику.

Знайшов згадку про це в [записі](https://life.pravda.com.ua/society/2011/03/11/74792/) виступу Оксани Забужко, але там також не пояснюється, що це таке. Це щось археолоґічне, але що?

Навіть пішов подивитися збірку есеїв Шевельова "[Не для дітей](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Sheveliov_Yurii/Ne_dlia_ditei.pdf)", згадану Забужко, але там це також лиш побіжна згадка.

Answer (score 4):

Рінерит - це неологізм, вигаданий Домонтовичем. Фактично йдеться про напис/зображення на камені (камінь - рінь, звідси рінерит, на зразок: дереворит тощо).

Comment: Додам посилання (можливо, варто додати їх прямо у відповідь): [рінь](http://sum.in.ua/s/rinj), [деревори́т](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=21630&page=736).

Comment: Вадиме, дякую за відповідь. Проголосовав за неї, бо це правильна відповідь. Можливо, поділитесь джерелами? Чи ви самостійно здогадалися?

Answer (score -1):

Можливо, це має якийся стосунок до справи: "have **rineryt** onland to march into the field princes"

https://www.google.com.ua/search?tbm=bks&hl=ru&q=rineryt

Comment: Мені здається, що це лише помилка розпізнавання. Насправді, там *ninety thousands*.

Comment: @Yola насправді це моє питання - це філологічний ребус, але відповідь є. Я навіть забув уже. Якщо знайду наукову статтю, якщо її вже видали десь, то напишу відповідь. Це дуже цікаве питання. Вам має сподобатись.